# kolla ansible deployment stuck at Nova API bootstrap container

Tags: installation, openstack-nova, kolla-ansible

I am deploying openstack (for kypo cyber range) using kolla-ansible. I have followed all the steps on [official guide](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html#recommended-reading). However I am stuck on Nova API bootstrap container for almost half a day. I have looked into mariadb.log file and it says

```
2022-01-17 11:40:36 1009 [Warning] Aborted     connection 1009 to db: 'placement' user: 'placement' host: 'kypo-virtual-machine' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-01-17 11:41:14 1028 [Warning] Aborted connection 1028 to db: 'placement' user: 'placement' host: 'kypo-virtual-machine' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-01-17 11:41:52 1047 [Warning] Aborted connection 1047 to db: 'placement' user: 'placement' host: 'kypo-virtual-machine' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-01-17 11:42:29 1064 [Warning] Aborted connection 1064 to db: 'placement' user: 'placement' host: 'kypo-virtual-machine' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-01-17 16:49:41 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT2.13542S), skipping check
2022-01-17 16:49:46 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT2.49028S), skipping check
2022-01-17 16:51:21 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT1.56325S), skipping check
2022-01-17 21:23:02 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT2.2194S), skipping check
```

All I can see is its a connection problem. Can anyone please guide how to get over it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work.

I got again issue with hanging on nova_api_bootstrap, as it was temporary containerand DB provisioning I suspect several things.

I discovered that I have 2 hours drift between server that is using to deploy openstack and destination hosts.

Please make sure that all your servers are in the TZ!

Since I have no time for dealing more with deployment I decided to use Xena instead of Yoga.

It works without issue.

I recommend you to have look also on ansible that is using to deploy ansible. Make sure that you specified proper version. I got some troubles before and I found that I have 2 installation od deploying machine (one from distro second from venv) Theoritically it shouldn't affect installation but better to have clear statement!

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the nova_api container and checking logs in `/var/log/kolla/nova/nova-api.log`.

In my case nova_api was using wrong fqdn when connecting to mariadb. Playbook succeeded after changing it.